# How do you pass Terraform count from a resource to a module?

Tags: terraform

How can I pass a list of values created from a resource to a module that expects a list of items? I've tried running `[count.index]` and reffering to the first item in the list `[0]` but I get the message that you can only pass a count object to `resource` & `data` blocks.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnets" {
  count                   = length(data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
  vpc_id                  = data.aws_vpc.selected.id
  cidr_block              = "192.168.${10 + count.index}.0/24"
  availability_zone       = data.aws_availability_zones.available.names[count.index]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = false

  tags = {
    Name                  = "private-subnet"
  }
```

---

```
module "my_module" {
  source                        = "../../"
  cluster_name                  = local.cluster_name
  subnets                       = aws_subnet.public_subnets[count.index].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform version 0.12+ has all the [goodies](https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/)!

I updated my call to the resource to loop back like the following:

```
[ for subnet in aws_subnet.public_subnets: subnet.id ]
```